# How to make a download link go through proxy? PHP

Tags: php, file, proxy, download

I have a proxy (IP + Port) and a file located on a different server.

I need people to download this file but through my proxy. The problem is, I don't want people to need to do stuff on there browser...

How do I do that?

Thanks! If you didn't understand something please ask.

Comment: ummm.... simply provide a link to a script on your server which fetches that file using curl and outputs it? they'd never see this background request. Note that you'll be doubling your bandwidth doing this - download+upload of the file each time.

Comment: thanks,can you explain how ti do it using cURL?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

Get the link:

```
$contents=file_get_contents("link-to-file");
```

put the contents:

```
file_put_contents("a temp path-with-file-type",$contents);
```

take user to the file:

```
header("location:your-temp-path-here");
```

probably is not the best way, but it works...

Also, if you're planning to make it slightly dynamic by using `$_GET` or `$_POST` for the link, you should be aware; that opens up a serious security hole and you should not do it.

Comment: Thanks, but do I have to wait till the file is fully downloaded to the server before the user can download it?

Comment: Yes, with the code above, the file will be downloaded onto the server *first* and then the headers will be sent to the client, promting for download from the server.

Comment: Than it's not good enough for me, becuase the file weight about 2 gigabyte each... And I need the download to start imediatly

Comment: That is what a proxy does. Downloads then content through the servers net connection, and delivers it as if it was its own content. You asked for a proxy. Also, I can't think of any other way to do it so its a proxy or nothing.

Comment: OK, so forget about proxy. Is there a way to download the file to my server and then to the client? While the server is downloading, so is the client...

Comment: No, not that I know of. Could be possible with some sort of streaming server application but my knowledge is limited to such. So I would say it's impossible.